# Rails 5: form_for vs form_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actionview

Rails 5 has introduced new form helper method `form_with`.

How does it differs with `form_for` and when is it more appropriate to use?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is really in preparation for rails 5.1 where only `form_with` should be used. It's meant to serve as a replacement for the two methods `form_for` and `form_tag`.

> `form_for` and `form_tag` in Rails were very similar, both allowed you to create a form tag but the first one uses model’s attributes to build create or update form, while the second one simply creates an HTML form tag with the passed URL as action.

Comment: could you add a link to that quote? I didn't see it mentioned in https://guides.rubyonrails.org.

Comment: That's because it's not a quote from rubyguides. :) I extracted that from the guides and just used blockquote for formatting.

Comment: Note that now with `form_with`, your labels won't automatically link up to your inputs like they did previously with `id`s being automatically added. For a label to properly pair up to an input field (with the `for` attribute) you now need to explicitly add the `id` attribute to the input.

Answer (score 15):

## Use form_with (more up-to-date)

- `form_with` is the latest.
- `form_for` and `form_tag` are obsolete.

## Why is there a change?

See [Kasper Timm Hansen's](https://github.com/kaspth) pull request - I cannot state it better than [pull request itself](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26976):

> form_tag and form_for serve very similar use cases. This
> PR unifies that usage such that form_with can output just
> the opening form tag akin to form_tag and can just work with
> a url, for instance.

This means you don't need to use form_tag if you don't have a model. You can use the `form_with` helper and it can still handle URLs.

**Note Re: Ids and Classes:** The Ruby 5.1 version of `form_with`, by default doesn't attach a class or id to the form.  For Rails 5.2 and later, however, `form_with` WILL automatically generate ids based on the model, if present—basically the same id behavior as `form_for`, so you will NOT need to manually specify them anymore. ([source](https://m.patrikonrails.com/rails-5-1s-form-with-vs-old-form-helpers-3a5f72a8c78a))

Comment: The last paragraph about default `id`s and `class`s is an important distinction! For a label to properly pair up to an input field (with the `for` attribute) you now need to explicitly add the `id` attribute to the input.

Answer (score 2):

Existing answers are great. What I also found helpful were the first few paragraphs [here](https://m.patrikonrails.com/rails-5-1s-form-with-vs-old-form-helpers-3a5f72a8c78a). Basically:

> `form_tag` and `form_for` are soft deprecated and they will be replaced by `form_with` in the future.

- DHH's proposal: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25197
- The pull request: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26976/files (I didn't read it, but it could be useful)