# Can't download file using send_data function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have requirement to download generated XML files to local machine. I compress files into .zip file and then use send_data function to download it. I am getting status:
`Sent data xml_idocs.zip (7.6ms) Completed 200 OK in 61ms (Views: 7.4ms | ActiveRecord: 4.6ms)`. The problem is that file is not downloading. I tried it on development and production environments using Opera and Chrome browsers. How can I fix it?

Code:

```
filename = 'xml_idocs.zip'
zip_filestream = Zip::OutputStream.write_buffer do |zos|
  zos.put_next_entry 'MATMAS05.xml'
  zos.print builder.to_xml
  zos.put_next_entry 'MATQM01.xml'
  zos.print builder1.to_xml
end
zip_filestream.rewind
send_data zip_filestream.read, :filename => filename, :type => 'application/zip', :disposition => 'attachment'
```

Comment: Try with just `send_data zip_filestream, filename: filename`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I found solution. Look in answers if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found problem on my own. The function was called on submit the form_with. I changed it to the form_tag and file downloading works correctly. I didn't do research why form_with does not work, so if someone knows the background I will appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your solution.

I had the same issue with a form that accepts a CSV and outputs a CSV but has no model relation. This must be something that will get worked out in the future (see also: [Rails 5: form_for vs form_with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868976/rails-5-form-for-vs-form-with) )

Here's what my code looked like:

```
                    <%= form_tag shipping_data_csv_path, multipart: true do %>
                        データCSV: <%= file_field_tag :csv %><br><br>
                        <%= submit_tag "データCSVを作成", class: 'btn btn-primary m-auto' %>
                    <% end %>
```